# Problems using a class with arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a micro-mouse maze solving robot, and I'm running into some issues with my class called Mouse. I get the error: expected ';' before 'right_motor' and 'left_motor'. I have no idea what is wrong with the code. I also am not sure exactly where I should declare my objects left and right motors. Here is all my code, thank you for your help.

Mouse.h:

```html
#ifndef _MOUSE_H_
#define _MOUSE_H_

class Mouse
{
    private:
    int speed;
    int motor_num;
    int direction;
    public:
    Mouse(int motor_number);
    ~Mouse();
    void run(int speed, int direction);
};

#endif
```

Mouse.cpp:

```html
#include "mouse.h"

Mouse::Mouse(int motor_number)
{
    motor_num = motor_number;
    speed = 0;
    direction = 0;
    return;
}

// Digital pin 11: DC Motor #1 / Stepper #1 (activation/speed control)
// Digital pin 3: DC Motor #2 / Stepper #1 (activation/speed control)
// Digital pin 5: DC Motor #3 / Stepper #2 (activation/speed control)
// Digital pin 6: DC Motor #4 / Stepper #2 (activation/speed control)

void Mouse::run(int speed, int direction)
{
    int M1 = 11;
    int M2 = 3;
    int M3 = 5;
    int M4 = 6;
    
    if(motor_num == 1)
    {
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            analogWrite(M1, speed);
        }
        if(direction == -1)
        {
            // FIXME: how do i do backwards?
        }
        if(direction == 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
        }
    }
    
    if(motor_num == 2)
    {
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            analogWrite(M2, speed);
        }
        if(direction == -1)
        {
            // FIXME: how do i do backwards?
        }
        if(direction == 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(M2, LOW);
        }
    }
    
    if(motor_num == 3)
    {
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            analogWrite(M3, speed);
        }
        if(direction == -1)
        {
            // FIXME: how do i do backwards?
        }
        if(direction == 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(M3, LOW);
        }
    }
    
    if(motor_num == 4)
    {
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            analogWrite(M4, speed);
        }
        if(direction == -1)
        {
            // FIXME: how do i do backwards?
        }
        if(direction == 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(M4, LOW);
        }
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Code in the Arduino sketch:

```html
#include "mouse.h"

void setup() 
{
  //begin communication with serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //pinmodes setup:
  //declare variables:
  Mouse right_motor(1);
  Mouse left_motor(2);
}

void loop() 
{
  //assign values to their respective variables:
  //BEGIN PROGRAM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class in MyMouse (...and update all reference of it), I think Mouse is an internal Arduino library

then, pay attention on Uppercase chars sometimes Mouse is uppercase and sometimes is lowercase

**Edit:**
this is Mouse Arduino library
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard